# Return element from jQuery plugin after promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a jQuery plugin that needs to execute some functionality syncronously and then return the original element so that the plugin is chainable.

```
$.fn.refresh = function(content) {
  $(this).fadeOut(function() { 
    $(this).html(content)
  }).fadeIn(); 
  return this
}
```

How would I make this simple plugin chainable so that it wouldn't return until after the .html() method?  I'm assuming this May be possible with jQuery promises.

Comment: move your return; `return $(this).fadeOut(...).fadeIn();`

Answer (score 1):

Change *how* you're returning the object:

```
$.fn.refresh = function(content){
  return $(this).fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).html(content);
  }).fadeIn();
};
```

Now with `$(whatever).refresh().foo()`, it's like appending `.foo()` after your `.fadeIn` call. At this point `refresh()` just becomes a macro of sorts.

```js
(function($){
  $.fn.refresh = function(content){
    return $(this).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).html(content);
    }).fadeIn();
  }
})(jQuery);

$('#foo').refresh('Hello, world!').animate({'font-size':'+=5pt'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo">Original content</div>
```

Comment: I need to be able to access the new content that was created with the HTML function. I created a fiddle showing how it is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/sLgnoomL/

Comment: Any other thoughts on this??

Answer (score 0):

Return the object being faded instead:

```
$.fn.refresh = function(content) {
  return $(this).fadeOut(function() { 
    $(this).html(content)
  }).fadeIn(); 
}
```